# MongoDB: Use an aggregation to multiply all values in a group together

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

How would I write a mongodb aggregation query to get the product of a set of values in a group (in other words, multiply them all together).

For example, say I have a list of documents like

```
_id: "1"
number: 12

_id: "2"
number: 3

_id: "3"
number: 6
```

I want to basically do something like the following:

```
db.documents.aggregate([
    $group: {
        product: { $multiplyAll: "$number" }
    }
])
```

From my example documents this query would result in (12 * 3 * 6) = 216

What are the equivalent aggregations of my made up $multiplyAll aggregator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently this is not possible to perform such operation in group stage. Refer [`here`](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-29339)

You will need to [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/) values followed by [`$reduce`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/) in [`$addFields`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/) stage to output calculated value in 3.4 version.

[`$reduce`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/) to [`$multiply`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/multiply/) all the array elements.

```
db.documents.aggregate([
 {
    "$group": {
      "_id": null,
      "numbers": {
        "$push": "$number"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "product": {
        "$reduce": {
          "input": "$numbers",
          "initialValue": 1,
          "in": {
            "$multiply": [
              "$$value",
              "$$this"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```